# Creating texture animation in swift Playground

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, swift-playground, wwdc

I want to make a basic game in SpriteKit and want to add some animations into it in swift playgrounds.
How can I add texture animations or even add Json file into my Playground

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a basic game in SpriteKit and want to add some animations into it in swift playgrounds.

Searching on Google finds quite a few introductory tutorials, here's one example https://www.checksimgames.com/spritekit-playground-introduction/

> How can I add texture animations or even add Json file into my Playground

A reading/watching list from the official Apple resources:

- [Introduction to Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/502/) - WWDC 2013 video
- [Getting Started with Sprite Nodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/getting_started_with_sprite_nodes) - Learn the basics about using images, also known as sprites, with SpriteKit.
- [Animating a Sprite by Changing its Texture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/animating_a_sprite_by_changing_its_texture) - Load a sequence of images and play them back at a rate you define, while optionally looping the resulting animation.